# When is it Appropriate to use Generics Versus Inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, inheritance

What are the situations and their associated benefits of using Generics over Inheritance and vice-versa, and how should they be best combined?

Thanks for the answer guys.

I'm going to try to state the motivation for this question as best I can:
I have a class as shown below:

```
class InformationReturn<T> where T : Info
{
    InformationReturn(Employee employee, List<T>) { ... }
}
```

Now suppose I have a repository that takes an InformationReturn argument, that has to strore different fields in a DB depending on the type of Info object T is. Is it better to create different repositories each for the type T is; one repository that uses reflection to determine the type; or is there a better way using inheritance capabilities over/with generics?

**Note**: other client code must operate differently based on the type of T as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're really different ideas altogether. Generics allow you to declare common "specific"  functionality (at the risk of sounding oxymoronic) in a general way. A `List<int>` doesn't function any differently from a `List<string>`, aside from the type of data that is held inside.

While inheritance could be used to do the same thing, I could create a `List` class, then an `IntList` and a `StringList` class that inherit from it. I could easily make these two classes function entirely differently, or have one offer functionality not available in the other one.

**Edit**

After reviewing the edit to the question, the answer sortof is "it depends." You can make arguments for both sides--and, indeed, LINQ to SQL and the Entity Framework are both a combination of both reflective inspection using generics, and strongly-typed entity classes and other repository classes. You can certainly take the approach that you're looking at, just know that, in general, a problem that can be solved either with reflection or with something else is LIKELY going to be faster when solved by the "something else." It comes down to how much of a tradeoff you want among performance, maintainability, readability, and reliability.

Comment: This answer helped me to point I should use generics when there is no difference in behavior and inheritance otherwise, thank you.

I have amended the question to be clearer as to my motivations.

Answer (score 35):

You should use generics when you want only the same functionality applied to various types (Add, Remove, Count) and it will be **implemented the same way**.  Inheritance is when you need the same functionality (GetResponse) but want it to be **implemented different ways**.

Comment: IMO, this is actually the best answer to this question! After searching SE for about 20 minutes..

Answer (score 13):

Generics and inheritance are two separate things.  Inheritance is an OOP concept and generics are a CLR feature that allows you specify type parameters at compile-time for types that expose them.

Inheritance and generics actually work quite well together.

**Inheritance:**

Inheritance allows me to create one type:

```
class Pen { }
```

and then later create another type that extends `Pen`:

```
class FountainPen : Pen { }
```

This is helpful because I can reuse all the state and behavior of the base class and expose any new behavior or state in `FountainPen`.  Inheritance allows me to rapidly create a more specific version of an existing type.

**Generics:**

Generics are a CLR feature that let me create a type like this:

```
class Foo<T> 
{
    public T Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I use `Foo<T>` I can specify what the type of `T` will be by providing a generic type argument:

```
Foo<int> foo = new Foo<int>();
```

Now, since I have specified that `T` shall be an `int` for the object I have just created, the type of `Foo.Bar` will also be `int` since it was declared of type `T`.

Comment: But when should you use each?

Comment: Picky bit of pedantry: you provide a generic type *argument*, i.e. T is the type parameter, int is the type argument. I'll let you decide whether that's worth an edit or not :)

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for pointing that out, pedantry is never unwelcome - goodness knows I deal out plenty of it myself :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I have amended the question to be more clear as to my motivation for asking.

Answer (score 11):

Use generics to specify an algorithm or type's behaviour which can be expressed in terms of some "unknown type" while keeping an API which is strongly typed in terms of that unknown type. The unknown type is known as a *type parameter* and is expressed in the code like this:

```
public class List<T>
{
    public void Add(T item)
}
```

(etc) - here `T` is the type parameter. Generic methods are similar:

```
public void Foo<T>(T item)
```

The *calling* code specifies the *type argument* it wants to work with, e.g.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("hi");
```

Use inheritance to specialize the behaviour of a type.

I can't really think of many places where they're alternatives to each other...

Comment: While I didn't downvote you, your answer is kind of useless. The OP is obviously new to .NET and your extremely short and concise dictionary definition will likely do very little to clear up any of his/her confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you clarify what you mean when you say 'expressed in terms of some "unknown type"'?

Also, I have amended the question to be a little clearer as to the context I ask the question in.

Answer (score 7):

Use generics when you want to create a "template" that can apply to many styles of unknown classes. Eg. Collections holding ??? are good candidates for generics. Inheritance is for when you have a base conecpt that children "are" an extension of that concept.

My general rules

- if you start defining properites as Object in your code and type casting a lot, then its probably time for generics.
- If you want to program against the "higher concept" as well as the derived class then its inheritance.
- If your class is going to wrap or work on a concerte class then its generics.
- If you are relying on the specifics of an unknown "yet to be defined" class then your probably better with generics.
- If you derived classes are "is a" then its usually inheritance
- If your superclass "uses some x" then its generics.

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance is much more about "is-a" (frog is an animal) where generics is about creating containers that act on typed data (List of T, Processor of T, etc).  They are **not mutually exclusive**.

You can have this if you want:

```
public class Base<T>
{

}

public class Derived : Base<Foo>
{

}
```

Comment: And in fact, you can have generic interfaces: public interface IBase<T> -> public abstract Base<T> : IBase<T> -> public class Derived : Base<Foo>

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I have more value to add to this question.

**Generics** are used when you want to maintain the same implementation while providing a different type definition to clients. Consider the following:

```js
const rabbitPopulation = new Population<Rabbit>();
const mousePopulation = new Population<Mouse>();

rabbitPopulation.add(rabbit) // ✅ will pass
mousePopulation.add(rabbit) // ❌ will not compile
```

both `rabbitPopulation` and `mousePopulation` have have the same method implementations while differing only by type signatures. When you model your code this way, you are implicitly saying that all "populations" should behave and act similarly.

Meanwhile, **inheritance** is used to extend or overwrite the implementation altogether.

```js
class RabbitPopulation extends Population {
  increase() { /* increase rabbit population in a specific way */}
}
const rabbitPopulation = new RabbitPopulation();

class MousePopulation extends Population {
  increase() { /* increase mouse population in a specific way */}
}
const mousePopulation = new MousePopulation();
```

As you can see, both `rabbitPopulation` and `mousePopulation` can now have their own implementations of similar methods. This is useful when want to capture a semantic idea across two objects (i.e both are populations) while allowing them to differ in behaviors (they have different methods on each).

You can **use both together** to express your modelling in a very rich way by making the base class a generic. Consider the following:

```js
class MousePopulation extends Population<Mouse> {/**/}
```

This way you can give similar implementations to basic functionalities across all semantic ideas of a "population" while providing specific implementations for subtypes of a population (i.e. MousePopulation) in a type rich way. But most times when you do this, you almost always want the `Population<T>` to be extended and might as well benefit from making your the `Population` class an `abstract` one.

```
abstract class Population<T> {}
class MousePopulation extends Population<Mouse> {}
```

I prefer this setup because you allow common semantic ideas to be captured in a base class while allowing specific functionalities to be extended by subclasses

Answer (score 0):

Neither inheritance nor parameterized types can change at run-time

Inheritance lets you provide default implementations for operations and lets subclasses override them.

Parameterized types let you change the types that a class can use.

But Which approach is best depends on your design and implementation constraints

> Design Patterns Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software