# What is the difference between a generic method limited by inheritance and a base class parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

Suppose I have the following code:

```
public class BaseClass { }
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass { }

public void GenericMethod<T>(T input) where T : BaseClass
{
 //code
}

public void NormalMethod(BaseClass input)
{
 //code
}
```

My question is what is the difference between the two methods? Is there any advantages or disadvantages to either method, and why?

Comment: In that particular scenario there really isn't any point in using a generic. Using the base class would be fine. Though there could be something in `code` that would warrant this

Comment: There is no difference in this case, you have found a perfect way to do the same things 2 different ways

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is cool about generics, why use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77632/what-is-cool-about-generics-why-use-them)

Comment: Contrast them with methods in a fluent API where the methods *return their input* after their action. Consider what the return types are then and what that means for fluent APIs.

Comment: Also [When is it Appropriate to use Generics Versus Inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799369/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-generics-versus-inheritance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two methods?

Basically none.

> Is there any advantages or disadvantages to either method?

At best there is a slight (compile-time) performance improvement when you use the non-generic version, since that doesn't need a specific version of the method to be compiled. Otherwise, there is nothing significant I can think of.

What could be a use case for using generics here:

- When you would return `T`;
- When `T` needs to derive from a class *and* an interface;
- If your class uses a type argument, you could follow that over specifying the required type again.

Comment: Thank you, i guess this is also a byproduct of adding generics.

Answer (score 1):

It makes little sense to use generics in the code you show.

On the other hand, if you were to *return* `T` as opposed to `BaseClass` from that method, the caller can access `T`-specific members instead of only members declared on `BaseClass` (unless they cast the return value).